# Split the string when alphabet is found next to a number using regex Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this

```
string = "3,197Working age population"
```

I want to break the string such that when number 3,197 ends and Working age population starts using regex or any other efficient method. In short I need only 3,197

Comment: Just split using this `(?<=\d)(?=[a-zA-Z])|(?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=\d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look at [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

string = "3,197Working age population"
r = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: not x.isalpha(), string))
print(r)
# '3,197'
```

*Take*s items from the string *while* an alphabet has not been reached. The result is reformed into a string using `join`